# Codeigniter csrf protection without form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, codeigniter, csrf

I have enabled csrf protection in Codeigniter. Using `form_open()`I'm able to produce a hidden csrf value that should be verified in my controller. However I'm not submitting any input fields but just passing a url paramater via the form action.

In my controller I don't need to set validation rules so I have

```
function delete_post($post_id = '') //post id passed via 3rd URL segment
{ 
    if (is_int($post_id) && valid_post($post_id)) //valid_post() returns true if post id exists
    {   
       $this->Posts_model->delete_post_model($post_id);         
       redirect('site');  
    }                   
}
```

Csrf protection doesn't seem to work without validation rules. Is it possible to make this work without passing `post_id` via a hidden input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [in the code of the Security class](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/src/d406084f5bef/system/core/Security.php#cl-84), CSRF protections only works with `POST` data (form validation also works with `POST` data actually).

You should to this the CodeIgniter way and use a `POST` request. If you're using AJAX, then simply change `GET` to `POST`, and if you're using a form, set the method to `post`. If you can't do it then you'll have to fight against CodeIgniter core code, so try to explain why. :)